# Proyecto Java: Batalla RPG

Tags: java

¡Hola a todos!
Estoy haciendo un proyecto y no sé si voy por buen camino.

El proyecto consta de realizar un pequeño juego por turnos, con temática del señor de los anillos, de tal manera que el primer jugador de los Heroes únicamente se enfrenta con el primer jugador del segundo equipo (Bestias), añadiendo además, que los diferentes tipo de jugador aumentan o disminuyen su ataque dependiendo de a quien se enfrente.

Los ataques de los Héroes se deciden con la tirada de dos dados, seleccionando el mayor de los dos, por el contrario el ataque de las Bestias solo se realiza con la tirada de un dado. Además los ataques solo se realizarán si el resultado de los dados es mayor que la defensa del oponente.

He creado varias clases y dentro de la clase Batalla es donde estoy intentando replicar los ataques.

Los problemas que tengo por el momento son:

- Que cambios tengo que implementar en el método batalla para poder realizar que el héroe de la posición 0 ataque únicamente a la bestia de posición 0.
- Como puedo hacer que una vez que se ataque, la vida con la que se parta en el siguiente turno sea la acumulada y no la inicial (ahora mismo solo consigo que siempre sea la inicial).
- Que cambios tengo que realizar para que si un elfo se enfrenta a un orco su ataque aumente en 10 puntos ya que con el código que tengo ahora no lo consigo.

!Muchas gracias!

Clase Ejército

```
public class Ejercito {
    String nombre;
    int puntosVida;
    int nivelResistencia;


public Ejercito(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.puntosVida = puntosVida;
    this.nivelResistencia = nivelResistencia;

}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getPuntosVida() {
    return puntosVida;
}

public void setPuntosVida(int puntosVida) {
    this.puntosVida = puntosVida;
}

public int getNivelResistencia() {
    return nivelResistencia;
}

public void setNivelResistencia(int nivelResistencia) {
    this.nivelResistencia = nivelResistencia;
}
}
```

Clase Heroes

```
import java.util.List;

public class Heroes extends Ejercito {
    int dado1;
    int dado2;

public Heroes(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
    super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);

}

public int mayorResultado(){
    dado1=(int) (Math.random()*(100+1));
    dado2=(int) (Math.random()*(100+1));
    System.out.println("primer dado:"+dado1);
    System.out.println("segundo dado:"+dado2);

    if(dado1 <dado2){
        return dado2;
    }else
        return dado1;
}

public int atacar(Bestias bestias) {
    int ataque = mayorResultado();
    int resultado = bestias.getPuntosVida() - ataque;
    boolean vid = getPuntosVida() >= 1;
    String men = "Las tiradas no superan la armadura de la bestia, pasa el turno";
    do {

        if (ataque > bestias.getNivelResistencia()) {
            System.out.println(bestias.getPuntosVida() + " - " + ataque + "=" + resultado);
            System.out.println("Datos actualizados de " + bestias.getNombre() + " (Vida=" + resultado + " Armadura=" + bestias.getNivelResistencia() + ")");
            return resultado;
        } else
            System.out.println(men);
        return 0;
    }while (bestias.getPuntosVida() != 0);

}


public boolean vida( List<Heroes> heroes){
    boolean vidas = getPuntosVida()<=0;
    if(vidas==false);
    System.out.println(getNombre()+" ha sido eliminado");
    return vidas;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Lucha entre "+getNombre()+" (Vida="+getPuntosVida()+" Armadura="+getNivelResistencia()+")";
}

}
```

Clase Bestia

```
public class Bestias extends Ejercito {

    int dado;

    public Bestias(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
        super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);

    }

    public int getNivelResistencia(){
        return nivelResistencia;
    }

    public int tirarDadosBestias(){
        return dado =(int) (Math.random()*(90+1));
    }

    public int atacarBestias(Heroes heroe) {
        int at = tirarDadosBestias();
        int result = heroe.getPuntosVida() - at;
        String mensaje = "La tirada no ha superado la armadura del heroe, pasa el turno";
        do{
            if (at > heroe.getNivelResistencia()) {
                System.out.println("Turno de las bestias, el resultado del dado es :"+at);
                System.out.println("Datos actualizados de: " + heroe.getNombre() + " (Vida=" + result + " Armadura=" + heroe.getNivelResistencia() + ")");
                return result;
            } else
                System.out.println(mensaje);
            return 0;
        }while(getPuntosVida()!=0);

    }

    public boolean vida( List<Bestias> bestias){
        boolean vidas = getPuntosVida()<=0;
        if(vidas==true);
        System.out.println(getNombre()+" ha sido eliminado");
        return vidas;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return " y "+getNombre()+" (Vida="+getPuntosVida()+" Armadura="+getNivelResistencia()+")";
    } 
}
```

Clase Elfo

```
public class Elfos extends Heroes {
    Orcos orco;
    Bestias bestia;


    public Elfos(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
        super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);
    }

    public void atacarElfo(){
        int ataElfo = mayorResultado();
        int incremento = 10;
        do{
            int suma = ataElfo+incremento;

        }while(atacar(orco)==1);
    }
}
```

Clase Hobbit:

```
public class Hobbits extends Heroes {
    Trasgo trasgo;
    Bestias bestia;

    public Hobbits(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
        super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);
    }

}
```

Clase Orco:

```
public class Orcos extends Bestias {
    Heroes heroe;

    public Orcos(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
        super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);
    }

    public int ataque() {
        return this.atacarBestias(this.heroe) + this.heroe.nivelResistencia * 0;
    }
}
```

Clase Trasgo:

```
public class Trasgo extends Bestias {
    Heroes heroe;

    public Trasgo(String nombre, int puntosVida, int nivelResistencia) {
        super(nombre, puntosVida, nivelResistencia);
    }

    public int ataque() {
        return this.atacarBestias(this.heroe);
    }
}
```

Clase Batalla:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Batalla {

    private static Heroes[] ejHero;
    private static Bestias[] ejeBestia;

    public Batalla() {
        ejHero = new Heroes[5];
        ejeBestia = new Bestias[4];
    }

    public static void batalla(List<Heroes> heroes, List<Bestias> bestias) {

        Heroes[] he = new Heroes[heroes.size()];
        he = heroes.toArray(he);

        Bestias[] be = new Bestias[bestias.size()];
        be = bestias.toArray(be);

        Ejercito[] conca = new Ejercito[he.length + be.length];

        int indiceHeroe = 0;
        int indiceBestia = 0;


        for(int i=0;i<heroes.size();i++){
            heroes.get(i).atacar(bestias.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Esta sería la clase Principal:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        List<Heroes> ejerHero = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Bestias> ejerBestias = new ArrayList<>();

        ejerHero.add(new Elfos("Legolas", 150, 30));
        ejerHero.add(new Humano("Aragorn", 150, 50));
        ejerHero.add(new Humano("Boromir",100, 60));
        ejerHero.add(new Humano("Gandalf",300, 10));
        ejerHero.add(new Hobbits("Frodo", 20, 10));

        ejerBestias.add(new Orcos("Lurtz", 200, 60));
        ejerBestias.add(new Orcos("Shagrat", 220, 50));
        ejerBestias.add(new Trasgo("Uglúk", 120, 30));
        ejerBestias.add(new Trasgo("Mauhúr", 100, 30));

        Batalla.batalla(ejerHero, ejerBestias);

    }
}
```

Comment: `conca[i] = he[indiceHeroe].atacar(be[]);` -> `conca[i]` es de tipo Ejercito, `atacar()` devuelve un `int`. Necesito que me expliques qué estás intentando hacer exactamente porque no lo he entendido muy bien, a qué te refieres con atacar uno a uno y por qué necesitas tenerlos todos juntos? Deberían los heroes atacar a las bestias? O van a atacar ambos juntos a un tercer enemigo y por eso los juntas?

Comment: Te explico, los Heroes atacan a las Bestias, con lo de uno a uno me refiero a que si por ejemplo la estructura de los heroes es; elfo, hobbit, humano y la estructura de las bestias es: Orco1, Orco2 y Trasgo1, el elfo solo se puede enfrentar a el Orco1, nunca podrá enfrentarse con el Orco2 ya que ese es el oponente del hobbit. Se me había ocurrido que lo mejor es juntarlos para poder enfrentarlos por eso lo de concatenarlos, pero no sé si es la mejor opción.

Comment: Entonces no los concatenes! Simplemente haz un bucle `for(int i = 0; i<heroes.length();i++)` y recorres la lista usando `heroes.get(i);` y atacas a `monstruos.get(i);` Habría qué ver qué pasa en el caso de que haya más heroes o más bestias, pero bueno, eso ya es cosa tuya :P

Comment: Ya he eliminado la otra pregunta así evitamos la duplicidad, gracias! :) Me da error lo que me comentas,¿ no sería mejor utilizar una colección en vez de un array estático?

Comment: No veo qué array estático vas a utilizar, si tu método está declarado así: `public static void batalla(List<Heroes> heroes, List<Bestias> bestias)`, tienes ahí las listas de heroes y bestias, ya son colecciones iterables. Solo necesitas recorrerlas llamando a los objetos y usando sus métodos `atacar()`.Qué error te da? Si tienes discord puedes compartir pantalla y explicarlo un poco mejor si quieres, que aquí es un poco difícil entenderse

Comment: No tengo discord pero te comento, me da error el siguiente error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4 por la línea heroes.get(i).atacar(bestias.get(i)). He editado el código de la publicación como me aconsejaste para que se entienda mejor y he añadido las clases que me faltaban. Por si se te ocurre una solución mejor. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Eso es porque una de tus listas es más grande que la otra. Estás intentando hacer pelear al 5º heroe contra el 5º monstruo... pero no hay 5 monstruos. Tendrás que ver qué hacer cuando eso sucede y comprobar que `heroe != null` y `monstruo != null`